# Perform restore without update?

Tags: itunes, restore, ios, ipad

I want to restore my iPad to factory settings. Its an iPad 2,1 running iOS 8.1:

[image]

However, when I connect to iTunes and click *Restore iPad...*, I get the message:

[image]

I'm not interested in 8.1.3, which is what a *Restore and Update* would result. In fact, I need to keep the iPad at 8.1.2 or lower due to operational requirements. So iOS 8.1 is fine by me.

How do I perform a restore without updating?

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the .ipsw file, press the Option key, then click Restore iPad. Navigate to the file and select it, and iTunes will use that for the restore.

Comment: No luck... I forgot to get the backup (or the IPSW signed). Its too bad Apple lied to me about the ability to revert/restore. I would not have allowed the upgrade if the information they provided was accurate.